# autoloading nested classes with composer

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-0, psr-4

I have created a very basic validator class.

My base code is in a my src/ folder, which gets autoloader with

```
"kevdotbadger\\Validator\\": "src/"
```

this works fine, so that when I instantiate a `new "kevdotbadger\Validator\ Validator` is gives me `src/Validator.php`

My Validator.php class then loads a bunch of sub-classes in my `src/Rules` directory. These are magically loaded by using the `__call`, so `->between()` should look for `src/Rules/between.php`. However, for some reason it won't usual load despite it being setup in my composer.json file.

My whole codebase is available at https://github.com/kevdotbadger/validator/

Have I setup my namespace correctly? I think the problem might be with php version 5.3, however I need to use version 5.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to keep the guidelines of psr-4 as you are using it to autoload.

- change the folder name "rules" to "Rules"
- Uppercase all your file names of classes like:

  ```
   between.php  -->  Between.php
  ```

that should do the job